# reg-ex one liner issue dealing with cisco configs

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to figure out reg-ex to solve a problem.

I'm working with an app that uses reg-ex and it chops up cisco configs at the interface level.

I need a reg-ex that will match when there is an IP address and not a line of no cdp enable.

so, I've tried:

```
ip address .*\n\s+(?=no cdp enable)
```

Some configs will have an IP address line and no 'no cdp enable' line, some will have both, some will just have the 'no cdp enable', etc.

Example should be a match:

```
interface Ethernet0/0
 description abcd
 ip address 192.168.1.85 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
 no ip mroute-cache
 half-duplex
!
```

Example should not be a match (it has the no cdp enable line):

```
interface FastEthernet1/0
 description xxxxxx
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
 no ip mroute-cache
 half-duplex
 no cdp enable
!
```

Example should not be a match (no IP address, has no cdp enable):

```
interface Serial0
 description test
 no ip route-cache
 no ip mroute-cache
 half-duplex
 no cdp enable
!
```

Anyone have any ideas / see where my statement is breaking down?

Comment: Use a Negative Lookahead `(?! ..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead before the description of the lines after the ip address:

```
(?m)^interface .*(\n(?!!).*)*?(.*ip address.*)(\n(?!.*no cdp enable)(?!!).*)*\n!
```